# Magento image upload problem

Tags: magento

Thanks in advance.

I am new to Magento, and I have created a module that directly shows products to the front of Magento.

In this module, I have created a form in customer account section where customers can fill out necessary data for product. Product data is saved successfully but I can't see the image on front. I have checked all the things the uploaded product from customer section also go to admin section for approval.

I just want to show image of product which I upload. My code is as follows for product save and image upload.

Sorry for my English.

-Jeet

```
$magentoProductModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$magentoProductModel->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
$magentoProductModel->setAttributeSetId(4);//old
//$magentoProductModel->setAttributeSetId(1);
$magentoProductModel->setTypeId('simple');
$magentoProductModel->setName($data[name]);
$magentoProductModel->setDescription($data[description]);
$magentoProductModel->setPrice($data[price]);
$magentoProductModel->setShortDescription($data[short_description]);
$magentoProductModel->setWeight($data[weight]);
$magentoProductModel->setStatus(1);
$magentoProductModel->setCategoryIds(array(3));
$magentoProductModel->setTaxClassId('None');
//$magentoProductModel->setSku('rand-sku-' .rand(1,20000) );

/* upload product image*/
$customerProductId=34;
$mediDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
$imagesdir = $mediDir . '/customersproducts/' . $customerProductId . '/';

if(!file_exists($imagesdir)){ 
    return false;
}

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($imagesdir) as $fileInfo) {
    //print_r($fileInfo);

    if($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->isDir()) continue;

    if($fileInfo->isFile()) {
        //echo $fileInfo->getPathname();         
        $magentoProductModel->addImageToMediaGallery($fileInfo->getPathname(),array('image','small_image','thumbnail'), true, false, true);
    }
    //else {
        //echo "no";
    //}
}
print_r($magentoProductModel);

/*upload script end */


$saved = $magentoProductModel->save();
$lastId = $saved->getId();
$customerProduct = Mage::getModel('customerpartner/customerpartner_product')->load($lastId);
$customerProduct->setProductId($lastId);
$logged_in_user=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$customerProduct->setCustomerId($logged_in_user);
$customerProduct->setCustomerId();
$customerProduct->save();
```

Comment: For future reference, use the like "101010" button on the post form to format your text as code. It also helps to have it consistently indented so that others can read it. Finally, please check the preview box below the post so that you can see these things in advance. Glad you solved your own problem, thanks for sharing your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys who visited this question i have solved the problem my self there is only a array of imaged required in the

following code works fine

```
$magentoProductModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$magentoProductModel->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
$magentoProductModel->setAttributeSetId(4);//old
//$magentoProductModel->setAttributeSetId(1);
$magentoProductModel->setTypeId('simple');
$magentoProductModel->setName($data[name]);
$magentoProductModel->setDescription($data[description]);
$magentoProductModel->setPrice($data[price]);
$magentoProductModel->setShortDescription($data[short_description]);
$magentoProductModel->setWeight($data[weight]);
$magentoProductModel->setStatus(1);
$magentoProductModel->setCategoryIds(array(3));
$magentoProductModel->setTaxClassId('None');
//$magentoProductModel->setSku('rand-sku-' .rand(1,20000) );

/* upload product image*/
$customerProductId=34;
$mediDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
$imagesdir = $mediDir . '/customersproducts/' . $customerProductId . '/';

if(!file_exists($imagesdir)){ 
  return false;
}

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($imagesdir) as $fileInfo) {

  //print_r($fileInfo);

  if($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->isDir()) continue;

  $visibility = array (
      'thumbnail',
      'small_image',
      'image'
      );

  if($fileInfo->isFile()) {
    $fileInfo->getPathname();         
    $magentoProductModel->addImageToMediaGallery($fileInfo->getPathname(), $visibility, false, false);
  }
  //else
  //{
  //echo "no";
  //}

}    

/*upload script end */


$saved = $magentoProductModel->save();
$lastId = $saved->getId();
$customerProduct = Mage::getModel('customerpartner/customerpartner_product')->load($lastId);
$customerProduct->setProductId($lastId);
$logged_in_user=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$customerProduct->setCustomerId($logged_in_user);
$customerProduct->setCustomerId();
$customerProduct->save();

} catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e;
  Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
  $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```